# Is Kafka the right solution for messages with dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have messages which are dependent.Ex. say we have 4 messages M1, M2, M1_update1,(should be processed only after M1 is processed),M3 (should be processed only after M1,M2 are processed).

In this example, only M1 and M2 can be processed in parallel, others have to be sequential. I know messages in one partition of Kafka topic are processed sequentially. But how do I know that M1,M2 are processed and now is the time to push M1_update1 and M3 messages to the topic? Is Kafka right choice for this kind of use-case? Any insights is appreciated!!

Comment: It is an interesting question. We have a similar use case, where the messages split into two semantic groups. Within the group order is irrelevant but between the groups there are order dependencies depending on the actual messages. I think that how we split the messages in the two groups might be a bad design decision from a computational standpoint regarding scalabilty. We try to find a better view on our problem so we can utilize streams for scalability. This means that the producer must decide which messages require strict ordering and these messages must be pushed to the same partition.

Comment: However.. the decision is computational intensive and we don't know yet how to scale it up.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is used as pub-sub messaging system which is highly scalable and fault tolerant.

I believe using kafka alone when your messages are interdependent could be a bad choice. The processing you require is condition based probably you need a routing engine such as camel or drool to achieve the end result.

Comment: Using same partition key, I can still sequence the messages M1,M1_update1. However, I’m still not sure, how to come up with a key for M3 (like composite key m1_m2?) so that it goes to right partition and naturally process in sequence. Can we achieve this with more than one Kafka topic and somehow add sequencing logic between consumers of different topics? I’m new to Kafka so trying to understand the possibilities Fyi, currently we are doing this logic in java in memory using dependency graphs(using some synchronized collections, etc) and able to process messages in multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically describing a message queue that guarantees ordering.  Kafka, by design, does *not* guarantee ordering, except in the case you mention, where the topic has a single partition.  In that case, though, you're not taking full advantage of Kafka's ability to maximize throughput by parallelizing data in partitions.

As far as messages being dependent on each other, that would require a logic layer that core Kafka itself doesn't provide.  If I understand it correctly, and the *processing* happens after the message is consumed from Kafka, you would need some sort of notification on the consumer end, which would receive and process `M1` and `M2` and somehow notify the producer on the other side it's now ok to send `M1_update` and `M3`.  This is definitely outside the scope of what core Kafka provides.  You could still use Kafka to build something like this, but there's probably other solutions that would work better for you.